# Mongo aggregation get unique count from $lookup phase

Tags: mongodb

I have three collections in Mongo: `jobs`, `categories`, and `orgs`. Each job posting has fields like `cat_id` and `org_id`. I do aggregations in order to `$lookup` (read: join) jobs with their categories and organizations. That works just fine (the code below). I paginate the results with `$skip` and `$lookup` phases. I also do a `$count` to get the total number of jobs within a given category (regardless of paginated results).

Question: is there any way (within the same single aggregation) to get the total count of unique `orgs` that have jobs within a given category (`cat_id`)?

Ultimately, what I want to achieve is: *"we've found X number of jobs from Y different companies"*. The `X` is already solved with `$count`. Now I'm struggling to get the `Y`.

Edit: I need to find the `Y` across *all* of the jobs within a category, not only in the paginated (20) results.

```
await mongo.jobs.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            cat_id: category._id
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            created_at: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "categories",
            localField: "cat_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "cat"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$cat"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "orgs",
            localField: "org_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "org"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$org"
    },
    {
        $setWindowFields: {
            output: {
                totalCount: {
                    $count: {}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $skip: 0
    },
    {
        $limit: 20
    }
]).toArray();
```

Comment: May I ask why? I must be missing something, but wouldn't it be the same number for all documents? If so, it doesn't really belong here. It is possible to do with another lookup, but you will be much better off by counting unique orgs on application level, cache the result for reasonable time and inject it to the paginated result.